# How big of a security risk is changing the permissions on my hosts file?

Tags: windows-10, uac, hosts

I regularly change the file because I add different subdomains to localhost when building websites locally.

To get around the hassle of having to go through elevated UAC every time I thought I might just give myself full access.

Is this a bad idea?

[image]

Comment: It means any process could in theory modify the file.  This means malware in theory, could redirect specfic domains, to a malicious host.

Comment: @Ramhound even though I added my user account to the list of permissions? I didn't alter the `USERS (DESKTOP-...` one

Comment: By default a process only has the permissions of the user the launched it.  This means malware, would have access to this file, and any file your user had access to.  The reason the file should have it's default permissions, is to require the elevation of a process's permission, before it's able to modify the file.  Its far less likely malware will be able to modify the file in that case.

Comment: I do the same. But when I do, I change permissions, update the file, revert the permissions back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moderate.

A program or virus that changes the hostfile could redirect traffic from a website that normally is fine to a different site and you wouldn't notice it.

However, given that usually altering the hostfile does require permission, its rarely attacked. But the wrong permission can lead to problems and you are likely to not notice it even if you have a trained eye.

However, even though IP Spoofing can make you go to a different site with the same url, they cannot spoof certificates. So if you go to a webpage and you are entering sensitive information or visit a login screen, do check for a https connection.

There is a chrome extension for altering your hosts file that will ask you to make the same kind of changes to your hostfile, so its not completely uncommon, but 95% of the people will not have their hosts file permissions set as suggested here, so it is still a very small target for an attack to go to.

I would still recommend against this though. Maybe if it is in your development environment, then it can be justified. But if its also the environment where you browse the internet frequently, I would suggest against it. If you need to edit the host file that much, I would look into a different solution, such as a DNS server.

Comment: I can imagine an attack that the hosts file is modified and then at the sametime, all traffic is routed through a proxy, thus making a MiTM attack possible.  Add in the possability of adding those fake certificates to the certificate store, and now you have a "secure" connection to a fake server.  You would only notice a problem if your browser like Chrome, pinned Google's certificates, so it always complains if the expected certificate didn't match what you were being sent.

Comment: I think I've been suitably deterred from doing this, I'll look into a local DNS server as you have suggested

Answer (score 2):

The answer can depend on various factors like how important this computer is.  The big impact is simply increasing risk is providing easier access for someone to alter the IP addresses that are provided to software when a name lookup occurs.  That might, or might not, be a very significant risk.

As you're working with content meant for Internet access, it would seem like you may frequently be exposed to potential opportunity to be attacked over the Internet.  So, based on the little bit I know from your question, I speculate that security precautions are likely worthwhile.

Still, even if you give yourself write permission to the hosts file, you may find you still need to work with UAC because the hosts file is in a protected directory.

You might want to consider an alternative option, such as using a DNS server (which, at least potentially, may be more convenient to update regularly).

Comment: If you give permissions like suggested above, you will no longer be bothered by UAC and can modify the hosts file at will.

Answer (score -3):

If you're part of an admin group already I don't see why you will have any repercussions adding yourself to have full access already. If you share your user account with someone else that is different because anyone can mess around with files and folders permissions, etc.

Comment: -1 because this is not true. The implications are far more serious.

Comment: @Frank: If we were still using XP, that would be true. However, since Windows Vista there's UAC which means you'll have to at least click "yes" to do anything with admin privileges, even as an admin.